# Java ExceptionInitializationError in static Block

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to call the URL retrieving method inside the static block, the Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError.

I am trying to get a WSDL url from the config file. this configuration data stored DB.

```
static 
{
    URL url = null;
    WebServiceException e = null;
    try 
{
    url = getVertexConfiguration();
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            e = new WebServiceException(ex);
        }
    }

private static URL getVertexConfiguration() throws MalformedURLException
    {
        try {
            configuration = configurationDAO.getByRefName("tax/vertex",
                    SecureSession.getUser().getDataDomain() != null ?
                            SecureSession.getUser().getDataDomain() : "app.cantata");
        } catch (B2BTransactionFailed b2BTransactionFailed) {

        }

        Map<String, DynamicAttribute> vertexTaxConfig = configuration.getConfigs();
        vertexWsdlUrl = vertexTaxConfig.get("vertexWsdlUrl").getValue().toString();

        return new URL(vertexWsdlUrl);
    }

}
```

I am getting static block, the Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError.

Comment: Don't do anything that can cause errors like this during class initialization; put  this stuff in the constructor instead. (It shouldn't even be static anyway; you might want to support multiple copies, such as for testing.)

Answer (score 0):

Why should you even try this? I think your `configurationDAO` is not even initialized at the moment you're trying to access it.

As we discussed in the comments, I would definitely recommend you, author, to inject your dependencies correctly, like:

```
@Service
public class ConfigurationService {

    private final ConfigurationDao configurationDao;
    private URL url;

    public ConfigurationService(ConfigurationDao configurationDao) {
        this.configurationDao = configurationDao;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        // your stuff here
    }
}
```

Or you can even initialize your `url` in constructor:

```
@Service
public class ConfigurationService {

    private final ConfigurationDao configurationDao;
    private final URL url;

    public ConfigurationService(ConfigurationDao configurationDao) {
        this.configurationDao = configurationDao;
        this.url = getVertexConfiguration();
    }

    private URL getVertexConfiguration() {
        // your stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: I am AutoWiring the configurationDAO like below   @Autowired
 static ConfigurationDAO configurationDAO;

Comment: @ArundhathiD why do you autowire the bean as static?

Comment: @ArundhathiD how do you initialize this bean?

Comment: How can I initialize the ConfigurationDao in static block

Comment: @ArundhathiD you should not do this

Comment: I tried using your approach. I am changing the the  existing class  which extends the Service  class. Service class here is readable only.  If I try to use the constructor to initialize ConfigurationDAO, there is no default constructor in Service class so it is throwing error with the above approach.

Comment: Is there any suggestion other than this?

Comment: @ArundhathiD yes, refactor your code, coz currently this it is insane

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is that static block is the earliest step when setup as class level initialization which even ahead of constructor calling. That is to say your dependency in static block such as that `configurationDAO` has not initialized yet. You shouldn't use static for it. Instead, you should make it a normal Instance method.

Answer (score -1):

You get ExceptioninInitializerBlock if there are some errors in the static initializer block. You handle only `MalformedURLException`, however, there are may be others.

You should add another `catch` for all exceptions and see what happens there.

```
static {
    URL url = null;
    WebServiceException e = null;
    try {
        url = getVertexConfiguration();
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        e = new WebServiceException(ex);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //real problem
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

That exception is a relaying mechanism for an error which occurred while running a static initializer.  The exception should have a cause, which will describe the actual error.  Per your description, above, there look to be three layers of exception: Error reporting from bean initialization, the `ExceptionInInitializer` exception, then the cause of the `ExceptionInInitializer` exception.  The exception processing **should** display all three layers, but might not, which will make uncovering the base exception more difficult.

From the ExceptionInInitializer javaDoc:

```
 * Signals that an unexpected exception has occurred in a static initializer.
 * An <code>ExceptionInInitializerError</code> is thrown to indicate that an
 * exception occurred during evaluation of a static initializer or the
 * initializer for a static variable.
```

As a fall-back, you could put inside `getVertexConfiguration` a try-catch on `Throwable`, and have the catch block print out the stack:

```
private static URL getVertexConfiguration() throws MalformedURLException {
    try {
        // Code omitted
    } catch ( Throwable th ) {
        th.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```